# Jobs search page windows title has invalid characters

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

The Jobs search page for a tag/keyword ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?searchTerm=java)) currently shows invalid characters:

[image]

The HTML my browser (Chrome Version 47.0.2526.106m on Windows 10 v1511/build 10586.36, useragent `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36`) receives for the title is:

```
<title>âjavaâ  Job Listings - Stack Overflow</title>
```

The expected behavior would be to have either java Job listings or "java" job listings, as opposed to odd characters delimiting the search term.

Comment: reproduced on FF42, Ubu 15.10, SO rev 3115

Comment: I think you mean `build 10586.36` _(Run... > `winver` > OS Build #)_

Comment: @DJDavid98 Thanks, corrected. I'm not sure Windows version could really affect it that much, but it's still good to have it right. Thanks!

Comment: Yep.  Also Chromium Version 46.0.2490.71 Built on 8.2, running on Debian 8.2 (64-bit)

Comment: If I get this weird title and then hit Search again, the invalid characters become smart quotes.

Comment: @svick Confirmed here as well.

Comment: @hexafraction You never know, the Windows 10 November update broke quite a few things.

Comment: Related: [Tags are duplicated in Job Listings](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313031/tags-are-duplicated-in-job-listings).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the report. SO Jobs is using an HTTP header proxied from Careers and HTTP headers don't support UTF-8.

Fixed by URL encoding the title when we pass it to SO which URL decodes it before it renders to the page.

Comment: Thanks for sharing what caused this; was a learning moment for me.