# Encoding bug in the title on the CV page for non-english characters

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, internationalization

Look like there's a encoding bug in the `<title>` for Stackoverflow CVs

https://stackoverflow.com/cv/clausjoergensen is presented like this:

[image]

Comment: Maybe same issue as http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/312948/73226?

Comment: Most likely same root cause, indeed.

Comment: For those who don't see it: it's in the *page* (tab) title, not the big text under `stackoverflow`. This was not obvious at first. (Need some freehand red circles!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the report. SO Jobs is using an HTTP header proxied from Careers and HTTP headers don't support UTF-8.

Fixed by URL encoding the title when we pass it to SO which URL decodes it before it renders to the page.