# Encoding issue in "Start your developer CV"-form

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

When trying to create a CV on SO Jobs, the predefined values for "Full Name" and "Location" have encoding issues.

Possibly related: [Encoding bug in the title on the CV page for non-english characters](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312984/encoding-bug-in-the-title-on-the-cv-page-for-non-english-characters)

**Example:**

[image: Example]

Comment: Is that some weird antialiasing, or does the "By clicking 'continue'" text have some really terrible kerning?

Comment: I'm using windows clear-type and Chrome 47. No fancy stuff. HTML and CSS does not seem to indicate any oddities. Probably just "the way it looks".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the report. As part of the account sharing with Careers used by the Jobs tab we make an internal API call that returns JSON in UTF8. However, for historic reasons, the JSON rendering doesn't render the UTF-8 BOM so the caller couldn't determine the encoding of it.

I've updated the caller to explicitly expect UTF8 and pushed a build to production.