# Tags are duplicated in Job Listings

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, new-nav

*Possibly related to [Jobs search page windows title has invalid characters](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312948/jobs-search-page-windows-title-has-invalid-characters), so possibly broken by the latest build.*

When searching a specific tag in Job Listings, the tag name is duplicated in the page (not just the title).

The [C++ tag](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/tag/c%2B%2B) for example:

[image]

Unless C++ has been renamed 'C++c++', the expected behaviour would be to only have one tag in the title/title of search results.

This issue affects *every* tag, not just [C++](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/tag/c%2B%2B). Note that this issue seems to be specific to the new beta navigation.

This is on Windows 7 Professional with Chrome 47.0.2526.106m.

Comment: I'm not seeing this behaviour right now, is it still occurring for you?

Comment: This is related to an A/B test we're running; one side of the test has some odd behaviour around page titles. It'll be fixed later today.

Comment: @DeanWard This' not yet fixed, is there any ETA for a fix in the works?

Comment: @cybermonkey we were planning to move to the side of the A/B test that doesn't exhibit this issue, but the holidays got in the way. It'll definitely be fixed, just not this week!