# Search keywords are repeated in results header and "Your Recent Searches"

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

When searching Jobs on SO, any keywords I enter get inserted into the results header and the "recent searches" item in a way that doesn't make sense. For example:

[image]

I'm not sure what an awesome job for "awesome" at awesome entails. It sounds too good to be true.

The behavior I would expect is for the search term to be mentioned just once in each of the results header and recent searches list, not twice in each spot. Personally, I favor the "Jobs matching 'X'" phrasing but "jobs for X" and even "X jobs" are also fine.

Comment: [Related feature-request](http://i.stack.imgur.com/DGIO9.png)

Comment: Same underlying issue as http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313031/tags-are-duplicated-in-job-listings. Will be rectified next week unless somebody gets to it before me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the report. We've now switched fully to the side of the experiment which doesn't exhibit this behaviour.